# How to pass a NumberFormat object to a method?

Tags: java, object, parameters, arguments, number-formatting

I'm trying to use a NumberFormat object to display a price. I'm very new to programming, my book isn't very helpful, nor is my teacher. I have a class called Product and a class called MyProduct, which is a subclass of Product. In the Product class there is a method called getPrice() that has no parameters. All it does is return the value for price. My task is to create a method in MyProduct called getPrice(NumberFormat nf) that returns the price, but formatted as currency. In the main method, if I use myproduct.getPrice(); I get the price, but unformatted (I know this is because it's calling getPrice() from Product, not getPrice(NumberFormat nf) from MyProduct. My question is what do I put in as an argument to stop getting a compile time error? I've tried getPrice(nf), getPrice(this), getPrice(price), just about anything I can think of and nothing works. Any help would be greatly appreciated and all relevant lines of code are posted below. Thanks in advance.

Below is the MyProduct class

```
public class MyProduct extends Product{
public MyProduct()
{
 super();
}

NumberFormat nf;

public String getPrice(NumberFormat nf) {

    this.nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    String priceFormatted = nf.format(price);
    return priceFormatted;
}
```

And here is ProductApp class

```
public class ProductApp {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    // display a welcome message
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Product Viewer");
    System.out.println();

    // create 1 or more line items
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        // get input from user
        System.out.print("Enter product code: ");
        String productCode = sc.nextLine();

        // Use a ProductReader object to get the Product object
        ProductDB db = new ProductDB();            

             MyProduct myproduct = db.getProduct(productCode);

        // display the output
        String message = "\nPRODUCT\n" +
            "Code:        " + myproduct.getCode() + "\n" +
            "Description: " + myproduct.getDescription() + "\n" +
            "Price:       " + myproduct.getPrice()+ "\n";
        System.out.println(message);

        // see if the user wants to continue
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("Bye!");
```

The line I need help with is

```
"Price:       " + myproduct.getPrice()+ "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are instantiating `nf` within your `getPrice` method then I would not bother passing it.  Maybe change the method name to something like `getPriceAsString` defined as

```
public String getPriceAsString() {

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();  // keep local
    String priceFormatted = nf.format(price);
    return priceFormatted;
}
```

Then you can call it as `myProduct.getPriceAsString ()`

**edit**

As per you comment

In main do

```
"Price:       " + myproduct.getPrice(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance())+ "\n";
```

And declare the method as

```
public String getPrice(NumberFormat nf) {
    return nf.format(price);
}
```

*I assume that `price` is correctly set*

Comment: Unfortunately part of the requirement of the assignment is that the method be named getPrice. I think I figured it out however, I had to use this.nf=nf and that made it work. Thanks for the suggestion though